# Inserting values to the database with hidden fields and checkbox

Tags: php, html

Good day!
Im currently having problems with inserting values with checkbox and hidden field. Any tips or solutions are greatly appreciated.

So my problem is this: I have a form with only checkboxes in it and a submit button and If I check one of the values in a checkbox a hidden upload field will be displayed the hidden value must be connected to the chosen value in the checkbox. How can I insert the hidden value to the corresponding checkbox value in a database. For example

HTML:

```
<label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="value[]" type="checkbox" value="Venue">
  Value 1
  <div id="hidden_fields">
    This is hidden: <input type="text" id="hidden_one" name="hidden_one[]">
  </div>
</label>
<br>
<label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="value[]" type="checkbox" value="Venue">
Value 2
  <div id="hidden_fields">
    This is hidden: <input type="text" id="hidden_one" name="hidden_one[]">
  </div>
</label>
<br>
```

PHP:(Updated) This is what I have now. when I dont check the 1st checkbox. the hidden_one in the 2nd checkbox isnt inserting

```
foreach($_POST['value'] as $key=>$value ){
  $hidden_one = $_POST["hidden_one"][$key];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sample (value, hidden_one) VALUES ('$value','$hidden_one')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

}
```

If I check value 1 and entered a sample1 in the hidden form and I check value 2 and entered a sample2 in the hidden form. sample 1 must be in the same column as value 1 and sample 2 must be in the same column as value 2. its not inserting properly

UPDATE:
So I changed the code into this 
`foreach($_POST['value'] as $key=>$value ){ 
$hidden_one = $_POST["hidden_one"][$key];`
 but the problem is sometimes its not inserting correctly. Sometimes hidden_one is empty in the database. I'm really lost at the moment. Can't find a solution elsewhere.

[This is my updated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4aFw.png)

Im seeing a pattern, when I skipped a checkbox like I check value1 then skip value2 then check value3. value3 hidden isn't inserted. Still not solved :( lol this is driving me crazy. at the verge of quitting. lol

Comment: Can you share your ```var_dump($_POST)``` so we can be sure the data sent is correct?

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria edited the post with the image link of var_dump

Comment: seems like you should ```foreach ($_POST["truevalue"] as $key => $value)``` instead

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria tried changing it. gave me errors. correction to my post in var_dump. it should be ($_POST["truevalue"] as $key => $truevalue). still not inserting properly :( truevalue is always inserted the problem is the hidden. sometimes it doesnt seem to appear on database

Comment: Sorry, I am confius with your var_dump just now because it is looping I think. Can you ```var_dump();die;``` right after ```<?php``` instead? And do not send screenshot. Please copy and paste the result.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria Im seeing a pattern. when I skipped a checkbox like I check value1 then skip value2 then check value3. value3 hidden isnt inserted. thank you for bearing with me. uh var_dump();die() right after <?php only displays array(0) { }

Comment: Sorry, when I said var_dump()... I mean var_dump($_POST)

Comment: its still displaying array(0){}. but if I put var_dump after the loop. this is what I get when I skipped a checkbox: array(2) { ["value"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Value1" [1]=> string(11) "Value3" } ["hidden_one"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(3) "www" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(5) "asdas" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" } } only checked value 1 and inputted a value in hidden field and same goes with value 3

Comment: Are you able to set the values of the checkboxes into the hidden input fields, or do you require assistance in that? Or is your only issue inserting your posted values into the database? Are you certain your post variables hold any value after being posted? Try to do some manual debugging by echo'ing out your sql to see if it looks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could insert the value of your checkbox into your hidden input fields, is by making a click function that takes `$(this).val()`, which is your clicked elements value. You can then put that value into a variable. You then go to target the *parent* element/container for the targeted checkbox and find the corresponding input field. You then simply set the value of that input field with the declared value of the checkbox.

Note that the notation for this JavaScript is in jQuery, and you will need to include a jQuery library in order for this solution to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('[name="value[]"]').click(function(){
        var mySelect=$(this).val();

        if( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
            $(this).parent().find('input[name="hidden_one[]"]').val(mySelect);
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().find('input[name="hidden_one[]"]').val("");
        }
    })
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('[name="value[]"]').click(function(){
  var mySelect=$(this).val();
  
  if( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
   $(this).parent().find('input[name="hidden_one[]"]').val(mySelect);
  }
  else {
   $(this).parent().find('input[name="hidden_one[]"]').val("");
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="value[]" type="checkbox" value="Venue 1">
  Value 1
  <div id="hidden_fields">
    This is hidden: <input type="text" id="hidden_one" name="hidden_one[]">
  </div>
</label>
<br>
<label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" name="value[]" type="checkbox" value="Venue 2">
Value 2
  <div id="hidden_fields">
    This is hidden: <input type="text" id="hidden_one" name="hidden_one[]">
  </div>
</label>
<br>
```

[Direct JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ch86dy0x/)

When it comes to inserting the value(s) into the database, it's hard for me to give a concise answer, because I don't have any debugging information on your application, so I don't know if you have structered it properly. I would assume you have either an AJAX function or a form action to post your values. As you noted in your own attempt, is that the values come up as an array that you will have to loop through. However, I am uncertain of the nested `foreach` loops.

Let me know if you need any further assistance, and in that case, update your question with potential error messages, corresponding form/ajax code, and if your PHP file holds any other relevant information, add that too.

A rough example could be:

```
<?php
$hidden_one_array=array_values($_POST['hidden_one']); //our posted array

$i=0; // iterator
$length=count($hidden_one_array); //length of the array

while($i < $length) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO sample (value, hidden_one) VALUES ('$value','$hidden_one_array[$i]')";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    $i++;
}
?>
```

What we're doing here is basically looping through the array, using the iterator value as our index pointer to each respective array index to insert into the database.

Also note that you should probably look into prepared statements to prevent sql injection. You are already using mysqli_ so might as well take advantage of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but the hidden one is entered manually. like when I check value 1 the user has to input on the hidden one. eq. when value 1 is checked, 'sample 1' is inputted on hidden_one. it should insert venue 1 and sample 1 on the database. my problem right now is. when value 1 isnt check all the hidden_one in other checkbox isnt inserting in the database.

Comment: It could be multiple issues. Firstly check the data of your array(s) to see if it/they contain the values you suspect it/they do(es). If all of that is okay, print out your sql in your loop so that you have a visual presentation. If everything looks normal, check for spelling errors. Copy paste the sql manually into your workbench to see if you get any errors there. If that doesn't give you any pointers, then try look at your connection. Are you getting any error messages as well to go off?